# How to solve function with floor: $a\left(\big \lfloor\frac {a} {2\pi}\big \rfloor + 1\right) = 100$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've never worked with equations that contains floor. I wonder how would you solve $$a\left(\big \lfloor\frac {a} {2\pi}\big \rfloor + 1\right) = 100$$

I looked it up in the internet but I don't get it. So what I found was that, lets say $\lfloor\frac {a} {2\pi}\rfloor$ is equal to $n$ and $$ n \le \frac {a} {2\pi} < n+1$$
and also $a(n+1) = 100$ but I can't continue from here. is there some way to calculate floor for general $a$ because I'm looking for value of $a$

$a$ is an integer

I got that I can try different variations like (100, 1), (50, 2), (25, 4) and (20, 5) and only 25 works but because I haven't solved an equation with floor function I want to know the techniques to solve it more mathematically and how it's done in general.

Comment: Is $a$ an integer? A real? It makes big difference

Comment: a is an integer

Comment: Then I suggest you edit the post

Comment: Then just try out all $a\mid100$. There's not that many.

Comment: Note:  your inequalities are not correct.  If $n=\big \lfloor \frac a{2\pi} \big \rfloor$ then $n≤\frac a{2\pi}<n+1$.

Comment: $a=25$ is the only solution

Comment: @VivaanDaga yes it is but how did you get it

Comment: In this case, there's no general way to solve these kind of problems, trial-and-error is (after possibly making some simplifications/bounds on $a$) the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{a}{2\pi} < \left\lfloor \frac{a}{2\pi}\right\rfloor+1<\frac{a}{2\pi}+1$$

If $a>0$, then multiplying everything by $a$ gives
$$\frac{a^2}{2\pi} < 100 < \frac{a^2}{2\pi}+a$$

The two inequalities can be solved to give
$$\sqrt{200\pi + \pi^2} - \pi<a<\sqrt{200\pi}$$

or approximately
$$22.1<a<25.1$$

We can either check the three integers in this range or just note the only factor of $100$ here is $a=25$.

---

If $a<0$, the inequalities become
$$\frac{a^2}{2\pi} > 100 > \frac{a^2}{2\pi}+a$$

and in a similar way to the above, we can check that there are no negative solutions.

Comment: ok that's interesting thanks a lot I got it now

Comment: Great. I think it was just a different way of setting out the inequalities, but glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, though very similar to what you proposed but presented differently, is to write $a=2n\pi+\theta$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$

The equation becomes $\ a(n+1)=100\iff(n+\frac{\theta}{2\pi})(n+1)=\frac{100}{2\pi}\ $ and we can bound: $$n(n+1)\le\frac{100}{2\pi}<(n+1)^2$$

whose only solution is $n=3$

$\frac{100}{2\pi}\approx 15.91$ gives interval $[12,16]$ for $n=3$, and negatives don't work, as it's either $[9,12]$ or $[16,20]$

Finally substituting $n$ gives $4a=100$ or $a=25$